# CronJob not able to start docker container

Tags: linux, docker, cron

I am trying to run a container using cronjob however my cron is not able to run container.

I have a cron task to invoke orchestrate.sh which starts a container

`crontab -l`

```
27 22 08 * * /tmp/compose/orchestrate.sh >> /var/log/composeerr.log
#have a newline
```

orchestrate.sh

```
#!/bin/bash -v
/usr/bin/docker run -d hello/helloworld:latest >> /somerror.log
```

somerror.log has a container id , however docker ps on host is not showing it.

If I run the command `/usr/bin/docker run -d hello/helloworld:latest >> /somerror.log`  on host its bringing the container up.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it possible that it wasn't the time to hit the cronjob? When do you want it to run?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: the corn was triggering i can see the log but docker container is not running. I had some echo statements to verify it

Comment: @jww The rules are not as clear to me when Docker is involved. It's now part of a normal developer's job to know how to build and deploy docker services. That's not really an Ops question.

Comment: @Srikant This is your first post here so I'll help you out a bit. I've reformatted your question. Try to spend a minimum of time making your question more readable (spelling, formatting) and add all info you have (list the exact output of the cron job). That's little to ask if you want people to spend their time answering your questions. Also don't forget to up vote comments/responses.

Comment: @Srikant  Does it work if you use `sudo docker run -d ...` in your cronjob?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. I have to change #!/bin/bash to #!/bin/sh in the shell file.

Answer (score 0):

The user the cronjob is running under must be able to start a docker container. On linux this is often the root user or a user added to that group.